# Как определить закрытие сокета?

Tags: java, сокет

Есть сервер, слушающий порт и множество клиентов, которые к нему подключаются, что-то делают и потом отключаются

```
public class Server
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
        while (true)
        {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            // Какая-то работа
        }
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
        // Какая-то работа
    }
}
```

Как узнать, закрылся сокет или нет (в том числе и не штатно)? Например, хочется отловить ситуацию, когда падает один из клиентов, чтобы корректно ее обработать.

Метод `isClosed()` возвращает `false` даже после падения второй стороны

Comment: Попробуй после закрытия сокета что-то отправить ему с другой стороны, скорее всего, появится эксепшн

Comment: Нет, исключения не кидаются, все нормально отправляется, хотя принимающая сторона уже упала